# Windows 8 Pro asks for activation again in Citrix Xen

Tags: windows-8, citrix

I have installed a Windows 8 Pro VM in Citrix Xencenter,

It asks for reactivating windows again, saying your hardware might have changed.

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid that or not

Comment: Hi there!  What do you mean by "again"?  How often is this happening? What's happening between boots?

Comment: @Karen Could be, but the lack of information provided makes it hard to figure out if it's the same situation (P2V2P type boots). It's bordering on Not a Real Question IMO. ;)

Comment: @techie007: P2V or not, the problem is due to running the OS in a VM, isn't it? I don't see any way to "avoid" this, since that will likely involve breaking the EULA.

Comment: @user893730 - Only one way provide the virtual machine instance it's own unique **unused** license key.

Comment: By again I meant two times, first it worked I believe after a restart it asked again, I haven't re entered the product key again. I bought a copy of windows just for this virtual machine and I haven't (and won't) used the licence on anything else.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate of the other question because it's xen citrix, not VirtualBox, the reason I asked this is that I was wondering if there is a way in xencenter to make a VM use the same hardware if restarted to avoid this problem.